# Visual Studio is not adding a Mocked method in the test coverage c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to Moq a method which is having SQL call.

Below is the Moq/Unit Test code:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
Mock<IDataAccessHelper> mockDataAccessHelper = new Mock<IDataAccessHelper>();
mockDataAccessHelper.Setup(x => x.ExtractDataFromDB(It.Is<string>(query => query.Contains("StudentTable")), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(dataTable);
```

// This is the data access class from where I am calling the ExtractDataFromDB method which I want to Moq

```
IDataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
object[] studentIds = new object[] 
{100,101,102};
List<Student> studentData= 
dataAccess.GetData(studentIds);
```

Below is the code for unit test:

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    private IDataAccessHelper DataAccessHelper { get; set; }

    public DataAccess(IDataAccessHelper helper)
    {
        DataAccessHelper = helper;
    }

    public List<Student> GetData(object[] studentIds)
    {
        string query = "SELECT StudentName,Address,Marks FROM StudentTable WHERE StudentId = @StudentId"
        DataTable table = DataAccessHelper.ExtractDataFromDB(query, studentIds);
        List<Student> studentList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                                     select new Student() {
                                         StudentName = dr["StudentName"].ToString(),
                                         Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),
                                         Marks = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Marks"])
                                     }).ToList();
        return studentList;
    }
}

public interface IDataAccessHelper
{
    DataTable ExtractDataFromDB(string query, object[] values);
}

public class DataAccessHelper : IDataAccessHelper
{
    public DataTable ExtractDataFromDB(string query, object[] values)
    {
        foreach (var id in values) {
            // SQL Call
        }
    }
}
```

In the constructor, IDataAccessHelper parameter is injected using DI.

But when I am calculating the coverage from Visual Studio(Test > Analyze Code Coverage) it is excluding the mocked method ExtractDataFromDB from test coverage. Method GetData which is calling this mocked method is included in the test coverage.

How can I include the mocked method in the test coverage since it is decreasing my test coverage percentage? Or any other approach?

Comment: Mark the method with the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute?view=netframework-4.8). You're not testing the code within it, so it isn't covered.

Comment: @stuartd: I also am aware of this attribute. But is it a good practice?

Comment: "Good practice" is not absolute. If you think you should test it, make it testable. If not, mark it with the attribute.